# Coulomb’s Law and divergence

Tags: electromagnetism

Assume there is an infinite line charge. Therefore, it has an electric field around it. If we calculate the divergence of the electric field \$\mathbf{E}\$ caused by the line charge, what is the sign of \$\operatorname{div}\mathbf{E}\$? Is it positive, negative, or zero?
Since the outflowing electric flux is inversely related to the displacement of the charge, we assume\$\operatorname{div}\mathbf{E}\$ to be negative. 
Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Hint: 1. It depends if the charge is positive or negative. 2. If the line is infinitely narrow, the divergence of E-field won't be finite.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered directly by the differential form of Gauss's Law

$$\vec\nabla\cdot\vec{E}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon}$$

In regions where there is no charge, the divergence is zero.

In regions where there is a positive charge, the divergence is positive.

In regions where there is a negative charge, the divergence is negative.

In the case of an ideal line charge, the charge density is infinite along the line, so the divergence of \$\vec{E}\$ will also be infinite (with sign depending on the sign of the charge). To avoid working with the infinities, it will usually be easier to work with the integral form of Gauss's Law.